# MVN Build Image - "dial tcp: lookup github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: maven, docker-image, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm trying to build a docker image using `mvn spring-boot:build-image -P<environment>` command but I'm getting an error:

```
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo BellSoft Liberica Buildpack 8.1.2
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              8.*             the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0               the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes  the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250             the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                           the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]       BellSoft Liberica JRE 8.0.292: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/8u292+10/bellsoft-jre8u292+10-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency jre
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/8u292+10/bellsoft-jre8u292+10-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/8u292+10/bellsoft-jre8u292+10-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/8u292+10/bellsoft-jre8u292+10-linux-amd64.tar.gz": 
dial tcp: lookup github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

Before I restart docker service I was getting another error:

```
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.7.1/spring-cloud-bindings-1.7.1.jar": 
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

What configuration Am I missing?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue I am having the similar issue

Comment: @MohsinKhan answered.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using spring-boot 2.4.2 and Java 11 version fixed the problem:

pom.xml

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
  <java.version>11</java.version>
  <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Console

```
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo BellSoft Liberica Buildpack 9.0.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_TYPE                 JRE             the JVM type - JDK or JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              11.*            the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false           enables Java remote debugging support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000            configure the remote debugging port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false           configure whether to suspend execution until a debugger has attached
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                          write heap dumps on error to this path
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true            enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary         configure level of NMT, summary or detail
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) arguments
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false           enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false           enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000            configure the JMX port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0               the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes  the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250             the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                           the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]       BellSoft Liberica JRE 11.0.13: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.13+8/bellsoft-jre11.0.13+8-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]         Verifying checksum
[INFO]     [creator]         Expanding to /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jre
[INFO]     [creator]         Adding 128 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPI_APPLICATION_PATH.default
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPI_JVM_CACERTS.default
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPI_JVM_CLASS_COUNT.default
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPI_JVM_SECURITY_PROVIDERS.default
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.launch/JAVA_HOME.default
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.launch/JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.append
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.launch/JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.delim
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.launch/MALLOC_ARENA_MAX.default
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
...
```

Answer (score 7):

I got similar error on Windows:

> dial tcp: lookup objects.githubusercontent.com: i/o timeout

Changing DNS to 1.1.1.1 solved the problem.

Comment: Pinning the DNS worked for me. I'm using Docker Desktop for Windows. I've set the DNS through the UI, by going to "settings -> Docker Engine" and adding DNS list to the Docker daemon file   "dns" : [ "1.1.1.1" , "8.8.8.8" ],

Comment: Thanks this worked for me as well - same issue on macOS Docker desktop! I'll open a new question as this question here is slightly different.