# bootBuildImage errors with `dial tcp: lookup github.com: i/o timeout`

Tags: spring-boot, docker, macos, docker-desktop, paketo

I'm building an SpringBoot image on macOS through docker using:

```
./gradlew bootBuildImage
```

I get an error of `dial tcp: lookup github.com: i/o timeout` at the `Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 10.2.6` step:

```
    [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 10.2.6
    [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
    [creator]       Build Configuration:
...SNIP...
    [creator]         Using Java version 20 from BP_JVM_VERSION
    [creator]       BellSoft Liberica JRE 20.0.1: Contributing to layer
    [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/20.0.1+10/bellsoft-jre20.0.1+10-linux-amd64.tar.gz
    [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
    [creator]     unable to get dependency jre
    [creator]     unable to download https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/20.0.1+10/bellsoft-jre20.0.1+10-linux-amd64.tar.gz
    [creator]     unable to request https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/20.0.1+10/bellsoft-jre20.0.1+10-linux-amd64.tar.gz
    [creator]     Get "https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/20.0.1+10/bellsoft-jre20.0.1+10-linux-amd64.tar.gz": dial tcp: lookup github.com: i/o timeout
    [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1

> Task :bootBuildImage FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The weird thing is that I can download the image using my browser when I click on the link `https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/20.0.1+10/bellsoft-jre20.0.1+10-linux-amd64.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

This is the network error inside your docker container. I deal with it after

```
sudo docker restart
```

on my linux host

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug in Docker Desktop or otherwise related to DNS misconfiguration.

I managed to fix the issue by adding the following line to Docker Engine config file `"dns": ["1.1.1.1","8.8.8.8"],` as suggested in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76823915/7483211).

This is where one can find the setting:
[image]